# Pass a control to a function using its own "Click" event

Tags: c#, event-handling, controls

I used [this CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9117/C-Star-Rating-Control) to make a custom star rating control and I want to pass it to a function using its `Click` event.

So for example,

```
private ctlRating_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ChangeOutline(???);
}

private ChangeOutline(??? control) {
     if(control.SelectedStar > 0) {
         control.OutlineThickness = 0;
     }
     else {
         control.OutlineThickness = 1;
     }
}
```

I tried using the `this` keyword, but that obviously just points to the form itself. I also tried using the `sender`, but that treats it as an object without any of its methods or values.

Is this possible besides just using the name of the control (which may be easier, but I want to know if I can do it this way)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast it

```
private ctlRating_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ChangeOutline(sender as StarRatingControl);
}

private ChangeOutline(StarRatingControl control) {
    if(control.SelectedStar > 0) {
        control.OutlineThickness = 0;
    }
    else {
        control.OutlineThickness = 1;
    }
}
```